# Giving a JPanel a percentage-based width

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

What's the easiest way to make a `JPanel` that takes up a fixed percentage of its parent container, by width?

Its width should update when that of its parent container changes.

I tried using `Box.createHorizontalStrut()`, but that doesn't update when the width of the `JPanel`'s parent container changes.

Comment: simple by using GridBagLayout and custom MigLayout, TableLayout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is a [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html). ([How to use?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html))

Using a GridbagLayout allows you to define [GridBagConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) for each single component you add.

These constraints include [`weightx`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx) which does exactly what it says on the tin. This is a relative value calculated across all components in that "grid-row", similar to distribution parts.

Be aware that the weightx only begins to come into play, when the preferred size of components is exceeded. Be aware that this may lead to interesting bugs, when setting minimumSize(), see also [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16298700/1803692)

Anyways: you can get the value you need for weightx by specifying it's percentage across the components in it's current row, or any multiple of that.

This means for a component to take 50% of the **available** parent container width, use `weightx = 0.5`. make sure that the row's weightx values add up to `1.0`

Comment: Just be aware that the weightx only applies to extra space. This means the two components you add to the layout must already have a preferred size in the ratio you want to maintain. Then as the frame grow/shrinks the ratio will be maintained.

Comment: @camickr didn't I already say something to that effect? "Be aware that the weightx only begins to come into play, when the minimum size of components is exceeded." Or is what I said there actually incorrect, and the preferred size is the relevant measure?

Comment: Yes the preferred size is the relevant measure. When you pack a frame the preferred size is used to size the frame. Then as the frame size changes the weightx ratio is used to change the widths in the appropriate ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a `SpringLayout`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SpringLayoutTest {
  private JComponent makeUI() {
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();

    JPanel p = new JPanel(layout);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 10));

    Spring pw = layout.getConstraint(SpringLayout.WIDTH,  p);
    Spring ph = layout.getConstraint(SpringLayout.HEIGHT, p);

    JLabel l = new JLabel("label: 5%, 5%, 90%, 55%", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    l.setOpaque(true);
    l.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1));

    JButton b = new JButton("button: 50%, 65%, 40%, 30%");

    setPercentage(layout.getConstraints(l), pw, ph, .05f, .05f, .90f, .55f);
    setPercentage(layout.getConstraints(b), pw, ph, .50f, .65f, .40f, .30f);

    p.add(l);
    p.add(b);
    return p;
  }

  private static void setPercentage(
      SpringLayout.Constraints c, Spring pw, Spring ph,
      float sx, float sy, float sw, float sh) {
    c.setX(Spring.scale(pw, sx));
    c.setY(Spring.scale(ph, sy));
    c.setWidth(Spring.scale(pw,  sw));
    c.setHeight(Spring.scale(ph, sh));
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new SpringLayoutTest().makeUI());
    frame.setSize(320, 240);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). This layout was designed for this purpose since none of the layouts from the JDK support this directly (and easily).

As a simple example you could have 3 panels at 25%, 25% and 50% of the width:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.X_AXIS);
rl.setFill( true );
JPanel panel = new JPanel( rl );
panel.add(red, new Float(25);
panel.add(green, new Float(25));
panel.add(blue, new Float(50));
```